# iOS Apple Review Team can't connect to my App using the credentials i gave them

Tags: ios, laravel, ionic-framework, ionic3, laravel-passport

I've sent my app for review in the Apple Store Connect, it contains a signing form in order to access its content. I’ve added a demo account credentials in order for them to review it.

Apple Team tried to connect to my app twice using 2 different credentials, they received a custom message that i made, showing that the login/password are wrong, and I’m 100% sure that the password is correct.

**Important edit:** The application is working correctly on real and virtual devices, and it connect normaly to the server using the form.

The server side is built using Laravel / Passport, and whenever the credentials are wrong: the server response with a 401 error:

```
    {
        error:{
            error: "invalid_credentials",
            message: "The user credentials were incorrect."
        },
        ...
        message: "Http failure response for https://mydomain.name/api/oauth/token: 401 Unauthorized",
        name: "HttpErrorResponse",
        ok: false,
        status: 401,
        statusText: "Unauthorized",
        ...
    }
```

N.B: This response shows up on the **Google Chome debug console** when i try to connect with false credentials, using the **Ionic Serve** command

I’ve built my app using Ionic 3, and here is how i interpret the server response to show the error message:

```
      this.userProvider.loginUser(this.email.toLowerCase().trim(),this.password).subscribe((response) => {
        this.storage.set('access_token',response['access_token']);
        this.storage.set('email',this.email.toLowerCase().trim());
      }, (response) => {
        if(response.status == 401) {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Invalid credentials',
            message: 'Please check your credentials.',
            buttons: ['Fermer']
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      }, () => {
        ....
      });
```

```
export class UserProvider {
  private apiUrl = 'https://mydomain.name/api';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  public loginUser(email: string, password: string) {
    return  this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + '/oauth/token', {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_secret: '******************************************',
      client_id: *,
      username: email,
      password: password
    }).map(response  => {
      return response;
    });
  }
}
```

Is it possible that the 401 response received by the Apple Team has another interpretation?
How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: so loginUser end point - did you ensure it does not require auth creds on your server end? if it returns 401 it means it does have auth enabled.

Comment: Im not sure i've understand your question, but the application is working correctly on real and virtual devices, and it connect normaly to the server using the form.

Comment: OK did you try to use that end point via postman or other external app? just to validate assumption?

Comment: Can you share this method: this.userProvider.loginUser

Comment: Hello, yes the login form is working everywhere, on Postman / Insmonia, on browsers, on a real iphone device, on virtual iphones (Xcode), in many android devices,

The only problem occurs on the Apple Store team side.
Thats why i've asked if its possible that the 401 may have an other meaning than wrong credentials.

Comment: I've added the method this.userProvider.loginUser to the question

Comment: I wonder why this problem still persist while Apple review process, I am also facing the same problem now, Apple rejecting the app saying they are unable to login but the same credentials are working fine on TF using dev and production environments both, have also collaborated with Apple review team over phone call but nothing has worked for us up-til now.